# How do I make 76 using only the numbers 2,0,1,9?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I must use each number 2,0,1,9 (only once) to come up with an answer of 76

Comment: What operations are allowed? Can we concatenate numbers?

Comment: i believe any operations are allowed.  i tried to spell out squared, but that was not allowed (2+0) squared * 19 = 76   they said the squared was an additional 2

Comment: @Chris Could you provide a source for this puzzle? Site policy dictates that you provide a source for a puzzle, in case it is not yours and evidently, you didn't come up with this puzzle on your own by your comments.

Comment: It's not mine.  it's a school assignment.  we have to make numbers 1-100 using only 2019

Comment: I have made all the other numbers, just can't get 76

Comment: Pretty sure most SE sites are against answering questions that are specifically for homework assignments.

Answer (score 7):

How about this

> $\frac{9}{.\overline{1}} - \frac{0!}{.2} = 76$

where

> $.\overline{1} = .111111\ldots$

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, well done.

Answer (score 5):

> $$-\log_{\sqrt{9}!-2}(\log(\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{...\sqrt{10}}}}_\text{158 square roots})$$
>  The "158" is not part of the equation. Normally, you'd write down all 158 square roots.

Comment: One closing bracket is missing. Can you explain while this formula equals to 76 ?

Answer (score 3):

> (2+1)! + 0! = 7, concatenate with 9 flipped over = 76.

Or:

> you used 19 in your guess, so I'm assuming concatenating the original numbers is allowed: (9+2)!!!!! + 10

Comment: dang they won't allow flipping or concatenate.  sorry, i just asked.  thank you for trying :)

Comment: Your second guess comes out to be 65.

Comment: @JR_M I’ve deleted one exclamation point, it should work now.

Comment: sorry, 65. I think you have one too many factorials

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how does the second one equal 76? I really don't get the operations, shouldn't it give out a huge number with all those factorials?

Comment: @S. M. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials

Answer (score 3):

I was doing a bit of research into factorials, and found both hyperfactorials (denoted by an $H$) and alternating factorials (denoted by an $AF$). Hopefully this answer fulfills your need.

> $AF(\sqrt{9} + 1) * H(2 + 0)$

First we can take the hyperfactorial of $H(2 + 0)$.

> $AF(\sqrt{9} + 1) * 4$

We'll then solve for the other pair of brackets.

> $AF(4) * 4$

Now we'll take the alternating factorial.

> $19 * 4$

And then some basic multiplication to get:

> $76$

Comment: Isn't the square root implicitly using an extra digit 2? Because sqrt that is (x)^1/2

Comment: By the Pickover definition, the superfactorial of 3 is about 10^10^10^10^36000. By the Sloane/Plouffe definition, the superfactorial of 3 is 12, or if you're counting 0, 2. Neither of them are 72.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out my error. I had taken the Sloane/Pouffe definition of superfactorial(4) and divided it by 4, not 24. Thankyou for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

> (9^2)-(2^2)-(1^2)-(0^2)=76 
>  If we take the square of all the numbers and apply subtraction then we get 76.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but you cant repeat any numbers.

Comment: According to OP's first comment, if you do a number's square you're already using up the 2.

Comment: Also, don't forget to hide your answers using ">!" at the beginning of a line

Answer (score -4):

> $(((\sqrt{9})!)!!-10)*2 = 76$

Here is the answer!  Finally!!!!!  And thanks to all who helped in the spirit of solving a puzzle.

Comment: My second answer is just as valid as this.

Comment: @Chris, you said concatenated numbers weren't valid.

Comment: My answer is surprisingly even more valid than this.